# Customizing ggplot Legend

Tags: r, graph, plot, ggplot2

Say I have a dataset like this

```
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
1  3  4  5  6  7  5
2  6  7  6  3  1  4
3  8  7  9  1  2  4
```

and code like this

```
ggplot(data=melt(vecDF), aes(x = variable, y=value)) + geom_violin(aes(fill=variable))+
scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","red","blue","blue","green","green"))+
 ggtitle("Coverage")+xlab("Location")+ylab("Value")
```

How do I alter it so that the I get a legend with simply three boxes instead of 6. A red, blue and green one with custom names. I can add a group column to the dataframe but as soon as I melt it it becomes useless for grouping the columns together.

Answer (score 0):

Add a group column to the melted dataframe:

```
vecDF_melted = melt(vecDF)

vecDF_melted$group = plyr::revalue(vecDF_melted$variable,
                                   c(X1='group1', X2='group1',
                                     X3='group2', X4='group2',
                                     X5='group3', X6='group3'))

ggplot(vecDF_melted, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=group)) + 
    geom_violin() +
    ggtitle("Coverage") +
    xlab("Location") + 
    ylab("Value")
```